# Connecting to Kubernetes cluster on AWS internal network

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, kubernetes

I have two Kubernetes clusters in AWS, each in it's own VPC.

- Cluster1 in VPC1
- Cluster2 in VPC2

[image]

I want to do http(s) requests from cluster1 into cluster2 through a VPC peering. The VPC peering is setup and I can ping hosts from Cluster1 to hosts in Cluster2 currently.

How can I create a service that I can connect to from Cluster1 in Cluster2. I have experience setting up services using external ELBs and the like, but not for traffic internally in this above scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an internal loadbalancer.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: cluster2-service
    namespace: test
annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

That will instruct the CNI to allocate the elb on a private subnet, which should make services behind it in the cluster reachable from the other vpc.

Answer (score 2):

You can create [internal LoadBalancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/load-balancing.html).

All you need to do is to create a regular service of type LoadBalancer and annotate it with the following annotation:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```